# control in sharepoint 2010 to implement calendar scheduler for scheduling appointments

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am a beginer in sharepoint and I want to know whether there is any control to implement calendar scheduler in sharepoint2010 so that i can create an appointment on a particular day or week

Comment: How to implement a appointment schedule? and  how it can be done using the calendar in sharepoint?

Answer (score 1):

Create a calendar list item in SharePoint. Export the list to access and create forms and code related to scheduling appointments according to your scheduling rules (no two appointments at the same time for the same person, or appointments must be no more than 20 minute blocks, no appointments on holidays or weekends, etc). Then again, I do not have SP 2k10 available yet, and have no control over how SP was setup. So, my answer applies specifically to the tools that I have available using SP 2k7.